# How to use NVD3 with rCharts in R with non numeric data

Tags: r, d3.js, rcharts

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(6L, 13L, 8L, 11L, 6L), TissueType = c("GC","Co","BE", "Tu", "Tu"), Sample = c("SL.Tum_TB05_00.fq.gz", "S.Tum_TB06.fq.gz", "S.Tum_T573.fq.gz", "Tum_TB0578.fq.gz", "TumTB0106.fq.gz"),Samplenum = 1:5), .Names = c("V1", "TissueType", "Sample", "Samplenum"), row.names = c("SL.Tum_TB05_00.fq.gz", "S.Tum_TB06.fq.gz", "S.Tum_T573.fq.gz", "Tum_TB0578.fq.gz", "TumTB0106.fq.gz"), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying out `rCharts` for the first time. I have managed to get the example working as [here](http://ramnathv.github.io/posts/rcharts-nvd3/index.html) but when I use my data, although there is no data, there is only an empty axis presented to me. I am trying to plot sample on the x axis and the "V1" value on the y axis. This is what I am using

```
 nPlot(TTypedAll2$Sample~TTypedAll2$V1,group=TTypedAll2$TissueType, data=TTypedAll2,type="scatterChart")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the group option as a string. Using your data and running:

```
nPlot(Sample~V1,group= 'TissueType', data=TTypedAll2,type="scatterChart")
```

You get this:
[image]

You can look at page 13 of the [rCharts doc](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/rcharts/latest/rcharts.pdf) to get more info on the type of the `nPlot` options. In this case,`group` needs to be a string.

Comment: OK so for some reason the rownames and Sample had been swapped incorrectly as I posted. I have now rectified this. The Sample column is a string in the dataframe but when I plot as suggested all the dots line up across a horizontal axis at 1 (the top of the graph). I would like to get a dot at the correct y point (as determined by the V1 value) for each value of Sample (which is a string) along the x-axis. I suppose this is awkward as each x axis string is not a numeric value as such.

Comment: Right I've sorted this. It turns out that the x axis doesnt have to take a string but should take a number (whether as a string or as an integer). So I had to create a new column with a number for each sample using TTypedAll2$Samplenum<-1:nrow(TTypedAll2). I then used this column as the x axis and then used the tooltip from this great blog: http://zevross.com/blog/2014/04/03/interactive-visualization-from-r-to-d3-using-rcharts/  to display the sample name when hovering over it. All within R studio. These are the best graphs ever.